# Failed to import appliance NS_ERROR 80070057

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, macintosh

I am trying to import Kali-Linux into my Virtual Box which is the latest version of Virtual Box and the most recent version of Kali Linux but get the following error:

```
Failed to import appliance....NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057)
```

It always stops at the same time left, i.e. 27 seconds left.  Help please, as I need this working to start an assignment.

[image: Kali]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I solved it but by installing the 32bit version instead.   I tried two different Macs and the same issue.  I suspect the issue will be resolved by the next release of Kali Linux so I will watch for the next release.